# Unable to use XPath to select input element based on content

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium Webdriver test where I want to wait for a text input field to contain a specific value before moving to the next step. I know what the value will be ("Town of Oakura") and it is set by JavaScript. I tried using the following c# code:

```
new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))
    .Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(DpNumber, "Town of Oakura"));
```

This just timed out every time. So I thought I would try XPath to wait for the field to be updated:

```
new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))
    .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//input[@id='DP_NUMBER'
                                                        and text()='Town of Oakura']")));
```

Which also didn't work. Using the console in Chrome I can use XPath to identify the element, defined as:

```
<input id="DP_NUMBER" type="text" name="DP_NUMBER"
     data-bind="textInput:DP_NUMBER" class="js-bound">
```

Expanding the element I can establish that the `value` is correct. But I can't find any permutation of XPath that locates the element based on its contents.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Can you consider updating the error stack trace in the Question area please? Thanks

Comment: It just times out - it never resolves the element based on the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextToBePresentInElement checks value in the element using getText method. getText method return empty value for the element which is of type input. To wait until the value in the input text become some value. you can use the following expected conditions.

```
new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))
    .Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementValue(DpNumber, "Town of Oakura"));
```

Also, the text() function will return empty for input box. So we can't use it in xpath.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the wait as something like

```
 (new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.findElement("//input[@id='DP_NUMBER']").getText().length() != 0;
        }
    });
```

I have taken this from selenium docs

Answer (score 0):

`text()='Town of Oakura'`, as well as `ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement`, is looking for exact match. Although it might look like an exact match any space or special character will throw the results off. Try using `contains`

```
new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))
    .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//input[@id='DP_NUMBER' and contains(text(), 'Town of Oakura')]")));
```

Comment: Thanks Guy I did try that permutation.